# WPF - Grid usage with item template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to place buttons that are bound to my custom field type `KField`, and I need 5 buttons to be placed in the shape of X - so on a 3x3 grid, I need buttons on the 4 edges, and in the middle. I have the following field type:

```
public class KField : ViewModelBase // ViewModelBase is a custom abstract INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private char _text;
    private bool _isEnabled;
    private int _x;
    private int _y;    

    public int X { get { return _x; } set { _x = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public int Y { get { return _y; } set { _y = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } }
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (_isEnabled != value)
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public char Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (_text != value)
            {
                _text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
}
```

And I use a `_fields` variable, that contains all the buttons and gets bound to the view:

```
_fields = new ObservableCollection<KField>();
_fields.Add(new KField { Text = _model.ModelFields[0], IsEnabled = true, X = 0, Y = 0});
_fields.Add(new KField { Text = _model.ModelFields[1], IsEnabled = false, X = 0, Y = 2 });
_fields.Add(new KField { Text = _model.ModelFields[2], IsEnabled = false, X = 1, Y = 1 });
_fields.Add(new KField { Text = _model.ModelFields[3], IsEnabled = true, X = 2, Y = 0 });
_fields.Add(new KField { Text = _model.ModelFields[4], IsEnabled = false, X = 2, Y = 2 });
```

And I created the `Fields` property of course:

```
    public ObservableCollection<KField> Fields
    {
        get { return _fields; }
        set
        {
            if (_fields != value)
            {
                _fields = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm using this XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="376" Width="534">
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" Margin="0,0,0,35">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Grid.Column="{Binding Y}" Grid.Row="{Binding X}" BorderThickness="0.3 " BorderBrush="Black" Command="{Binding ButtonPressed}" Content="{Binding Text}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, this puts all my buttons into the first cell of the grid. The text and the enabled/disabled states work OK, so the binding does happen, but it disregards all the X and Y properties. What am I missing? How can I place these buttons the way I want to? Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if I'm right, but I think you need to place your grid inside the `ItemsControl` and maybe even inside your `DataTemplate` although I'm even less sure about placing it there. Try that and see if anything changes? Because you're saying right now to put the button in its ancestor grid, but the ancestor isn't a grid but a datatemplate if that makes sense. See if that helps?

Comment: See this link if that helps: https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/12/21/455-using-itemcontainerstyle-to-bind-data-elements-in-a-collection-to-a-grid/

Answer (score 3):

The issue was, that the `ItemsControl` was just separate from the grid. If I put a grid inside the `ItemsControl`, and provide the binding of the coordinates in `ItemContainerStyle`, it works fine:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="376" Width="534">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button BorderThickness="0.3 " BorderBrush="Black" Command="{Binding ButtonPressed}" Content="{Binding Text}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}">
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Style.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding X}" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Y}" />
                </Style.Setters>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention the use of the ItemContainerStyle, where you have to put the X and Y Bindings instead of in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: I actually didn't know you can do that! Guess I still have much to learn :)

Comment: @Markinson Oh haha, I found the solution separately from what you've linked! :D Thanks for your help though! :) Much appreciated!

Comment: Oh haha ;) no problem! Glad you found an answer